# Scala - Recovering function name

Tags: scala

I have this timer object:

```
object Timed {
  def apply[T](fn: => T)(implicit logger: Logger): T =
    measureDuration(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace.last.getMethodName, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, fn, logger)
}
```

That I would like to like this (in another `class`):

```
def test(): Unit = {
  implicit val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("testTimed")
  Timed { someFunction() }
}
```

AND - I would like to recover the string `"someFunction"` in `Timed.apply` to pass instead of the stack's last method's name. Is that even possible?

I tried to look at macros, but got lost pretty quickly. I think this one is going to be a bit of challenge. Any idea?

More details:

Inside `Timer.apply`, we have only `fn`, but when we write `Timed { someFunction() }` there is a function name: `someFunction` - that string (`"someFunction"`) is what I want to recover and print out.

For cases such as `Timed { 2 + 2 }` or `Timed { x }`: we can assume that by convention users would then call `Timed("addition") { 2 + 2 }` and `Timed { x }` would be removed in code review. In other words, I am interested only in `Timed { someFunction() }`.

Comment: Your question is unclear: in the title, you ask about "recovering lambda name", but a) lambdas are *anonymous* which literally translates to "unnamed", and b) there are no lambdas anywhere in your code. As to the code in your question body, your spec is incomplete: what should the result be for `Timed { 2 + 2 }`? What should it be for `val x = someFunction(); Timed { x }`?

Comment: Inside `Timer.apply`, you have only `fn`, but when you write `Timed { someFunction() }` there is a function name: `someFunction` - that is what I want to recover and print out. For `Timed { 2 + 2 }` or `Timed { x }`: we can assume that by convention users would then call `Timed("addition") { 2 + 2 }` and `Timed { x }` would be removed in code review. In other words, I am interested only in `Timed { someFunction() }`.

Answer (score 1):

Short of messing with macros, the best way to get the function name inside `Timed.apply` is to just pass it in as an argument. E.g.,

```
Timed("someFunction")(someFunction)
```

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I do **not** want, because it's a repetition. I precisely want the code inside `Timed` to figure out that the name is `someFunction`, and macros are entirely welcome :-)

Comment: @Frank I don't know too much about Scala macros, but this may be helpful: https://github.com/Log4s/log4s/blob/1155339023744cb6d2f9809cfff8ea5b57c59868/src/main/scala-2.11/org/log4s/LoggerMacros.scala#L18